# Ionic 1 change text on template dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to modify an ionic 1 project where I need to dynamically change the text on a tempate when it opens.

In the controller.js I have:

```
//Settings
  $scope.settingsData = {};
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/settings.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal2 = modal;
  });

  $scope.closeSettings = function() {
    $scope.modal2.hide();
  };

  $scope.settings = function() {
    $scope.modal2.show();
  };

  $scope.doSettings = function() {
    console.log('Doing Settings', $scope.settingsData);

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeSettings();
    }, 1000);
  };
```

The template looks like this:

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">App Settings</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeSettings()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>

    <div id="myid">Text in here needs to be replaced with something when it opens</div>

  </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

So if I have a variable:

```
var myvar = 'Something to replace';
```

Then when the template opens the var above could be the text in div myid which is in the template

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll try to answer your question.

in your controller :

```
$scope.myvar = 'new text here !';
```

in your html file :

```
<div id="myid">{{myvar}}</div>
```